# Creating a central log out view controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am working with Parse, and one thing I have implemented in my app is their built in `PFLogInViewController`. This controller will be presented at two times in the application - when the app first starts and the user is not logged in, and when the user taps the "`Log out`" button of my application (logging out takes them back to the `PFLogInViewController`, as you are required to sign in to use the app). 
 I would like to set this up using `Storyboard`, as that is how the rest of my app is laid out. 
 How could I set up a central view controller (a `PFLogInViewController`) that is accessed at these two times? I have already Subclassed `PFLogInViewController` and set it up, I just need advice on how to place it in `Storyboard` and how to connect it to my views. 
 To make this question help as many people as possible, the general theme of my question is how does one establish a central `Login/ViewController` that can be accessed at different points in the application using `Storyboard`. 
 Attached is the basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. I haven't been able to successfully segue to the initial TabBarController, and I'm not sure how I should make the LoginController the initial ViewController if I can't segue.
 I am programming in Swift, if it matters.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending upon your application. One way is drop a UIViewController onto the storyboard, but don't wire it up to anything (no segue). Create a storyboard id for it such as "MyLoginVC". Do the necessary subclassing of UIViewController and attach the class to your VC. Then, when you want to display the VC simply do the following or wire this up to your logout button

```
id destinationVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLoginVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
```

In addition, if you want to show the login VC as the very first VC when you launch your app, then perhaps in your AppDelegate

```
  // Load Root view controller
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  self.rootVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
  self.window.rootViewController = _rootVC;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Load Login view controller
  id initialVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLoginVC"];
  [initialVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
  [_rootVC presentModalViewController:initialVC animated:NO];
```

When you finish with your login VC (i.e. successful login) then within login VC

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

and alternatively instantiate your first VC with something similar to the following from within login VC. Note, since you loaded the root VC above first, it is already there with the login VC sitting over it. When you dismiss login VC, the underlying root VC should be ready to rock and roll. Otherwise you can do the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    RootTabBarController *tbController = (RootTabBarController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootTabBarController"];
    [self presentViewController:tbController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! I ended up using the modal view controller implementation for the initial view controller, and for the logout button. Thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an unwind segue. Here are the instructions I follow for an unwind segue: https://github.com/bradley/iOSUnwindSegueProgramatically

If the link dies, here is what it said:

In your storyboard create two view controllers.

Subclass UIViewController twice, once for each of the view controllers in your storyboard.

Connect these view controllers to the view controllers in your storyboard.

Make a segue between the first view controller and the second by control+dragging from the first to the second.

Click on the segue you created and give it an identifier in the attributes inspector.

Make a button on the first view controller and link it to an IBAction in its UIViewController subclass.

When this button is pressed, the second storyboard should appear. To make this happen (we are doing it programatically) put the following into the implementation of the action you just created:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfTheSegueBetweenOneAndTwo" sender:self];
```

Create a second method in the implemention of the first view controller with the following:

```
- (IBAction)returnToStepOne:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"And now we are back.");
}
```

This method will work to unwind any view controller back to this view controller. Notice that we implement the method in the view controller we wish to return to.

Go back to the storyboard. Focus in on the second view controller. If it is active, you should see a dark bar beneath it with 3 symbols on it. One of these is orange and when hovered over will show the name of the UIViewController subclass that this view controller represents. Control drag from this symbol woth the green symbol that means 'Exit'. You should see all available segue unwinds, which XCode automatically enumerates when you create segue unwind implementations inside UIViewController subclasses that you have shown on your stroryboard. Hence, you should see the segue 'returnToStepOne' as an option. Select it.

In your storyboard's document outline, find the section for the second view controller. You should see an item listed below it with a grey symbol that says something like "Unwind segue from ... to Exit." Click on this item.

Important and easily missed step follows!

On the right side of your storyboard, in the attributes inspector, you should see two fields. One for 'Identifier' and one for 'Action'. In most cases, the 'Action' field will have the text 'returnToStepOne:', which is what we want, but the 'Identifier' field will be blank. Fill this field with the text: 'returnToStepOne' (note that we leave out the colon).

Create a button on the second view controller and link it to an IBAction in its UIViewController subclass.

In the implementation for the method you just created, put the following code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"returnToStepOne" sender:self];
```

Run the application. You should now be able to unwind from the second view controller to the first.

Comment: +1 for an awesome tutorial, but I found that the other answer addressed my application more specifically. However, I will surely reference this answer in the future. Thank you!